# Winscp from VBScript - "get" doesn't download files

Tags: vbscript, download, ftp, sftp, winscp

I am new to both Winscp and VBScript and I need a script that downloads files with yesterday's date in the filename from a remote server. I tried everything I could and ended up creating 2 different scripts, both of which seem to have the same issue.

From the log file, I can see that Winscp opens the directory, correctly interprets the filename pattern, lists the directory contents, but then just exits instead of getting the specified files. I can't figure out what's wrong. Any help is appreciated!

Here are the 2 scripts I wrote:

First:

```
main
Sub main()

Dim mydate
Dim cmd1, cmd2_sftpcmd, cmd3, cmdActivity
Dim wshShell 
Set wshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 

'------------------------------ SET VARIABLES --------------

mydate = date - 1
MM_DD_YYYY =Right("00" & Month(mydate),2) &"-"& Right("00" & Day(mydate),2) & "-" & CSTR(Year(mydate))

cmd1="@echo off & cd C:/Program Files (x86)/WinSCP/ "
cmd2_sftpcmd = "winscp.exe /console /log=""E:/DATA/script/log_winscp_get_files.log"" /loglevel=0 /command ""open sftp://XXXX@XXXX.com -privatekey=""C:/putty/XXXX/xxxx.ppk"""" ""cd /exports"" ""option transfer binary"" ""get ""filename_" & MM_DD_YYYY & "_*.csv.gz"" E:/DATA/"" ""close"" ""exit"""
cmd3="exit" 
cmdActivity = "cmd /k " & cmd1 & " && " & cmd2_sftpcmd & " && " & cmd3 '


'------------------------------- RUN WScript Shell--------------
wshShell.Run cmdActivity

End Sub
```

Second:

```
Function SFTPDownload()

Dim mydate, mmddyyyy, sFTPScript
Set oFTPScriptFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oFTPScriptShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

mydate = date - 1
mmddyyyy = Right("00" & Month(mydate),2) &"-"& Right("00" & Day(mydate),2) & "-" & CSTR(Year(mydate))

sFTPScript = sFTPScript & "option batch on" & vbCRLF
sFTPScript = sFTPScript & "option confirm off"& vbCrLf
sFTPScript = sFTPScript & "option transfer binary" & vbCrLf
sFTPScript = sFTPScript & "open sftp://XXXX@XXXX.com -privatekey=C:/putty/XXXX/xxxx.ppk" & vbCrLf
sFTPScript = sFTPScript & "cd /exports" & vbCrLf
sFTPScript = sFTPScript & "get filename_" & mmddyyyy & "_*.csv.gz E:/DATA/" & vbCRLF
sFTPScript = sFTPScript & "close" & vbCrLf
sFTPScript = sFTPScript & "exit" & vbCrLf


sFTPTemp = oFTPScriptShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%TEMP%")
sFTPTempFile = sFTPTemp & "\" & oFTPScriptFSO.GetTempName

'Write the input file for the sftp command to a temporary file.
Set oFTPScript = oFTPScriptFSO.CreateTextFile(sFTPTempFile, True)
oFTPScript.WriteLine(sFTPScript)
oFTPScript.Close
Set oFTPScript = Nothing  

sCmd = """C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\winscp.exe""  /console /log=""E:/DATA/script/log_winscp_get_files.log"" /loglevel=1 -script=" & sFTPTempFile 
oFTPScriptShell.run sCmd

Wscript.Sleep 1000

' Get rid of temp file used for input to sftp
oFTPScriptFSO.DeleteFile(sFTPTempFile)

Set oFTPScriptFSO = Nothing
Set oFTPScriptShell = Nothing
End Function

SFTPDownload()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh god! I just realized that I kept looking for a wrong date pattern (mm-dd-yyyy instead of yyyy-mm-dd)... Both of the scripts actually work. I guess I'll leave it here in case someone needs it in the future.
Cheers!